# save only edited listbox entries

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listboxitems

If I've some existing entries in Listbox. When I click on edit button then I'll be able to edit those entries. After editing one or more entries when again I clicked on button, I want to save only those entries which are edited. How could I do this? Please suggest some solution.

Comment: One solution is to start coding, then once you get the general idea of what you want i.e a working prototype then report back here with issues and or errors that you are encountering in regards to if the item you are editing is not saving as expected..

Comment: Actually my main problem is: [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096832/wpf-change-datatemplate-for-one-change)

Comment: Word of advise, don't post an additional link to your existing issue post it in your initial question meaning `update your question` with all the relevant issues you are experiencing as well as `YOUR` existing code not someone else's code.. it's misleading

Comment: Sorry. But, do you have any idea for this issue?

Comment: yes I have a great idea, my idea is to `Vote to close` stop looking for others to do your work this is not a difficult task please show some effort

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways of doing that. You can save each entry into a `List<T>` on every edit, or you can cache (pre-store) the ListBox items and after finishing editing you can compare the latest with the previous and extract out the edited items. IMO the first approach is better and easier to implement.